# how to shorten passing jquery listener with event

Tags: jquery, events, parameters

How can I shorten the following snippet :

```
$(".preventClick").click(function(e){
   preventClick(e)
})
```

to something like :

```
$(".preventClick").click( preventClick(e) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to pass the reference to the 'preventClick' function to the click method:

```
$(".preventClick").click( preventClick );
```

This assumes that the 'preventClick' method is defined elsewhere.